# Add external style and script file via new meta data options

Tags: javascript, next.js, next.js13

I need to add the following external css and scripts in my NextJS app (NextJS version 13.4.13).

Style
`https://company.com/statics/1/package/dist/1/styles/dls.min.css`

Script
`https://company.com/statics/1/package/dist/1/scripts/dls.min.js`

How can I add it?

I tried the following.

File path: `app-name/src/app/layout.js`

```
import 'https://company.com/statics/1/package/dist/1/styles/dls.min.css'
import './globals.css'
import Script from "next/script";


export const metadata = {
  title: 'title',
  description: 'desc',
}

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        {children}
        <Script type="text/javascript" src="https://company.com/statics/1/package/dist/1/scripts/dls.min.js" />
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

But it throws error:

Failed to compile:

> https://company.com/statics/1/package/dist/1/styles/dls.min.css Module
> build failed: UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from
> "https://company.com/statics/1/package/dist/1/styles/dls.min.css" is
> not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme). Webpack supports "data:"
> and "file:" URIs by default. You may need an additional plugin to
> handle "https:" URIs. Import trace for requested module:
> https://company.com/statics/1/package/dist/1/styles/dls.min.css
> ./src/app/layout.js

Comment: could you use `<Head>` tags from Next and then just use a standard `<link>` tag in there?

Comment: @JonahCRowlinson The error is gone but the styles not loading. Believe Head no longer fits for this purpose in NExtJS version 13.4 and above.

Comment: ah - seems NextJS docs say to not use a CDN and all external files should be downloaded, as can be seen [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/styling/css-modules#external-stylesheets), in the Good to know box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NextJS suggest not to include CSS from an external CDN, and instead all external files should be downloaded into the project source.

> **Good to know**: External stylesheets must be directly imported from an npm package or downloaded and colocated with your codebase. You cannot use .

[Source](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/styling/css-modules#external-stylesheets)